# How to format a table stored inside a RichText control (ck-editor) using css?

Tags: xpages

Take an xpage containing a RichText control (this is Domino 8.5.3, so we're using ck-editor).
Quite often tables are used by the users to structure their RT content. One request is to make sure that those tables have a unique formatting esp. regarding cellspacing and cellpadding.

Through Firebug I see that those inserted tables are setting their borders and cell* parameters using html attributes. And of course, since the html inside the editor has been created using "manual" html the xsp engine can't have much influence here.

Before we start writing some client side js to try and remove or manipulate those attributes: maybe there is someone having a neat idea of how we could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output from the RichText control is, AFAIK, always rendered within a `<div>` with a class called `"domino-richtext"` one could use CSS to get that identical appearance you're looking for (at least I think with "unique" you mean identical or uniform).

I pasted an HTML structure below, where the user added some `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`:

```
<div class="domino-richtext xspInputFieldRichText" id="view:_id1:inputRichText1">
  <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="1" dir="ltr">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p dir="ltr">Some more content besides the table...</p>
</div>
```

When the following styles are applied / defined within a theme or stylesheet, all tables, created within the RT control will look the same.

```
.domino-richtext table {
    border-collapse:collapse; /*remove spacing or padding when defined*/
}

.domino-richtext table tbody tr td,
.domino-richtext table thead tr th {
    padding: 0; /*define / remove padding*/
    border:1px solid #eee; /*border definition for all tables*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input; that's what we thought and tried (we used ".xspInputFieldRichText" as a reference point in our css, but "domino-richtext" is giving the same negative result). For some resaon it's not working that way: none of the formatting instructions are making an appearance in the resulting html

Comment: oops - having written that, and then tried again with some more tweaking, "all of a sudden" it's working. - Thanks!